# How do i stop the price from overriding with new price in cart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have created a swiggy clone, I was working on the cart menu and cart, but what happens every time I add something new to the cart it's changing the price of all items in the cart how do I stop that?   every item should get its price. I know I did something wrong in the slice logic please help me with this.

cartSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const savedCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")) || {};

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: {
    items: savedCart.items || [],
    totalPrice: savedCart.totalPrice || 0,
    discountPrice: savedCart.discountPrice || 0,
    deliveryFees: savedCart.deliveryFees || 0,
    price: savedCart.price || 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    addItem: (state, action) => {
      const existingItemIndex = state.items.findIndex(
        (item) => item.card.info.id === action.payload.card.info.id
      );

      if (existingItemIndex !== -1) {
        state.items[existingItemIndex].count += 1;
      } else {
        state.items.push({ card: action.payload.card, count: 1 });
      }
      state.price =
        action.payload.card.info.price / 100 ||
        action.payload.card.info.defaultPrice / 100;

         state.totalPrice +=
        action.payload.card.info.price / 100 ||
        action.payload.card.info.defaultPrice / 100;

      state.discountPrice = (state.price * 10) / 100;
      state.deliveryFees = (state.price * 5) / 100;
      console.log(state.price);

      // localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(state.items));
    },

    removeItem: (state, action) => {
      const itemIdToRemove = action.payload.card.info.id;
      const itemIndexToRemove = state.items.filter(
        (item) => item.card.info.id === itemIdToRemove
      );

      if (itemIndexToRemove !== -1) {
        state.items.splice(itemIndexToRemove, 1);
      }
      // localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(state));
    },
    clearCart: (state) => {
      state.items.length = 0;
    },

    decreaseItemCart: (state, action) => {
      const { id } = action.payload;
      const itemToDecrease = state.items.find(
        (item) => item.card.info.id === id
      );
      state.price = state.totalPrice;
      if (itemToDecrease && itemToDecrease.count > 1) {
        itemToDecrease.count -= 1;
        state.price = state.price * itemToDecrease.count;
        state.discountPrice = (state.price * 10) / 100;
        state.deliveryFees = (state.price * 2) / 100;
        console.log(state.price);
      }
    },

    increaseItemCart: (state, action) => {
      state.price = state.totalPrice;
      const { id } = action.payload;
      const itemToIncrease = state.items.find(
        (item) => item.card.info.id === id
      );

      if (itemToIncrease) {
        itemToIncrease.count += 1;
        state.price = state.price * itemToIncrease.count;
        state.discountPrice = (state.price * 10) / 100;
        state.deliveryFees = (state.price * 2) / 100;
        console.log(state.price);
      }
    },
  },
});

export default cartSlice.reducer;

export const {
  addItem,
  removeItem,
  clearCart,
  decreaseItemCart,
  increaseItemCart,
} = cartSlice.actions;
```

cart.js

```
import { CARD_IMG } from "../utils/constants";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  removeItem,
  decreaseItemCart,
  increaseItemCart,
  clearCart
} from "../store/cartSlice";

import React from "react";
const Cart = () => {
  const CartItem = useSelector((store) => store.cart.items);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const totalPrice = useSelector((store) => store.cart.totalPrice);
  const discountPrice = useSelector((store) => store.cart.discountPrice);
  const deliveryFees = useSelector((store) => store.cart.deliveryFees);
  const price = useSelector((store) => store.cart.price);
  console.log("price in cart", price);
  const finalAmount = price + deliveryFees - discountPrice;

  const handleDecreaseItem = (menuItem) => {
    dispatch(decreaseItemCart({ id: menuItem.card.info.id }));
  };

  const handleIncreaseItem = (menuItem) => {
    dispatch(increaseItemCart({ id: menuItem.card.info.id }));
  };

  if (CartItem.length === 0) {
    return (
      <div className="empty">
        <h1 className="text-black mt-10">Cart is empty</h1>
        <p className="text-black mt-10">Add items</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div className="  ">
      <div className="flex justify-center">
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold uppercase text-black">CART</h1>
        <button
          className="   uppercase font-bold text-lg bg-orange-600  text-center rounded-lg  p-2 text-white m-2
          hover:text-orange-600 hover:bg-white hover:border-orange-500 border-1
          "
          onClick={() => {
            dispatch(clearCart());
          }}
        >
          CLEAR CART
        </button>
      </div>

      <div className="outer  grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 h-[70vh] w-[70vw] mx-auto">
        <div className="menu-item   overflow-x-scroll  ">
          {Array.isArray(CartItem) &&
            CartItem.map((menuItem) => (
              <div
                className="flex gap-10 justify-start mb-4"
                key={menuItem.card && menuItem.card.info.id}
              >
                <div className="image  inline-block ">
                  <img
                    className="w-[164px] h-[164px]  object-cover block rounded-md aspect-square"
                    src={CARD_IMG + menuItem.card.info.imageId}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className=" w-[80%]  ">
                  <span className="text-lg font-semibold">
                    {menuItem.card.info.name}
                  </span>
                  <p className="line-clamp-1">
                    {menuItem.card.info.description}
                  </p>
                  <p className="font-bold mt-1 text-black inline-block opacity-70">
                    {price.toFixed(2) * menuItem.count}
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    {" "}
                    ₹{" "}
                    {(menuItem.card.info.price.toFixed(2) / 100 ||
                      menuItem.card.info.defaultPrice.toFixed(2) / 100) *
                      menuItem.count}
                  </p>
                  <p className=" inline-block ml-2">
                    (
                    {
                      (fixedPrice =
                        menuItem.card.info.price.toFixed(2) / 100 ||
                        menuItem.card.info.defaultPrice.toFixed(2) / 100)
                    }
                    {"X"} {menuItem.count})
                  </p>

                  <div className="buttons flex justify-between  mt-9 ">
                    <div className=" justify-start">
                      <button
                        disabled={menuItem.count <= 1}
                        className="bg-orange-500 disabled:bg-orange-500/50 disabled:cursor-not-allowed text-white font-bold w-8 h-8 rounded-md"
                        onClick={() => handleDecreaseItem(menuItem)}
                      >
                        -
                      </button>

                      <p className="font-bold inline-block  text-black w-8 h-8 ml-6">
                        {menuItem.count}
                      </p>
                      <button
                        className="bg-orange-500 text-white font-bold w-8 h-8 rounded-md"
                        onClick={() => handleIncreaseItem(menuItem)}
                      >
                        +
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="">
                      <button
                        className="border ml-20 border-orange-500  text-xs font-bold text-white  bg-orange-500 p-2 px-4 rounded-md
                          hover:text-orange-500  hover:bg-white hover:border-orange-500  "
                        onClick={() => {
                          dispatch(removeItem(menuItem));
                        }}
                      >
                        Remove
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>

        <div className="order-page shadow-md md:m-0   p-4">
          <h2 className="text-xl font-bold border-b pb-4 mb-6">
            Order Summary
          </h2>
          <div className=" leading-10 font-bold">
            <div className="price-item flex mb-6 justify-between">
              <p className="text-gray-600">Price ( {CartItem.length} items)</p>
              {/* <p className="font-bold text-lg">₹ {CartItem.items.toFixed(2)} </p> */}
              <p className="font-bold text-lg">₹ {price.toFixed(2)} </p>
            </div>
            <div className="discount text-gray-600 flex mb-6 justify-between">
              <p className="">Discount (10%) </p>
              <p className="font-bold text-black text-lg">
                {" "}
                - ₹ {discountPrice.toFixed(2)}
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className="delivery text-gray-600 flex mb-6 justify-between">
              <p> Delivery charges (2%) </p>
              <p className="font-bold  text-black text-lg">
                ₹ {deliveryFees.toFixed(2)}
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className="reward border-b">
              <p className="mb-6 text-black">
                {" "}
                You'll save ₹{discountPrice.toFixed(2)} on this order {" "}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="total-amt flex text-2xl font-bold mt-8 justify-between mb-4 ">
            <p className=" "> Total Amount </p>
            <p className="text-orange-500 ">₹{finalAmount.toFixed(2)}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="place-order ">
            <button
              className="w-full block border uppercase font-bold border-orange-500 text-lg
              text-center p-4 rounded-md 
              hover:text-white   text-orange-500  hover:bg-orange-600  bg-white   "
            >
              Place order
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

menuItems.js

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { CARD_IMG } from "../utils/constants";
import { addItem, removeItem } from "../store/cartSlice";

const RestaurantMenuItems = ({ items }) => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleAddItem = (menuItem) => {
    console.log("add clicked");
    try {
      dispatch(addItem(menuItem));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error in handleAddItem:", error);
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="">
      {items &&
        items.map((menuItem) => (
        
          <div
            key={menuItem.card && menuItem.card.info.id} 
            className="p-2 m-2 border-b-2   border-gray-400  text-left flex justify-between"
          >
            <div className="w-1/2 ">
              <div className="p-2">
                <span className="font-bold">{menuItem.card.info.name}</span>
                <p className="font-bold mt-1 text-black opacity-70">
                  ₹{" "}
                  {menuItem.card.info.price
                    ? menuItem.card.info.price / 100
                    : menuItem.card.info.defaultPrice / 100}{" "}
                   
                </p>
                <p className="text-base mt-2 text-black opacity-70 w-80">
                  {menuItem.card.info.description}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="container-ib p-4 w-3/12 relative">
              <img
                className="container-i w-full relative h-32 rounded-lg"
                src={CARD_IMG + menuItem.card.info.imageId}
              />
              <div className="container-btn">
                <button
                  className="w-20 h-8 absolute bottom-1 ml-2 left-24 transform -translate-x-1/2 bg-green-500 text-white border-none cursor-pointer m-0 p-1rem outline-none rounded-md font-bold text-xs shadow-md transition duration-200 ease-out hover:shadow-lg hover:text-green-500 hover:bg-white"
                  onClick={() =>   handleAddItem(menuItem )}
                >
                  ADD
                </button>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default RestaurantMenuItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

In both IncreaseItemCart and DecreaseItemCart remove state.price = state.totalPrice and additem logic is you are updating state.price globally

```
reducers: {
  addItem: (state, action) => {
    const existingItemIndex = state.items.findIndex(
      (item) => item.card.info.id === action.payload.card.info.id
    );

    if (existingItemIndex !== -1) {
      state.items[existingItemIndex].count += 1;
    } else {
      state.items.push({ card: action.payload.card, count: 1 });
    }

    // Calculate price for the added item only
    const addedItem = state.items[existingItemIndex] || state.items[state.items.length - 1];
    const itemPrice = addedItem.card.info.price / 100 || addedItem.card.info.defaultPrice / 100;
  
    state.totalPrice += itemPrice;
    state.discountPrice = (state.totalPrice * 10) / 100;
    state.deliveryFees = (state.totalPrice * 5) / 100;
  },

  // ... other reducers

  decreaseItemCart: (state, action) => {
    const { id } = action.payload;
    const itemToDecrease = state.items.find(
      (item) => item.card.info.id === id
    );

    if (itemToDecrease && itemToDecrease.count > 1) {
      itemToDecrease.count -= 1;

      // Calculate price for the decreased item only
      const itemPrice = itemToDecrease.card.info.price / 100 || itemToDecrease.card.info.defaultPrice / 100;
      state.totalPrice -= itemPrice;
      state.discountPrice = (state.totalPrice * 10) / 100;
      state.deliveryFees = (state.totalPrice * 5) / 100;
    }
  },

  increaseItemCart: (state, action) => {
    const { id } = action.payload;
    const itemToIncrease = state.items.find(
      (item) => item.card.info.id === id
    );

    if (itemToIncrease) {
      itemToIncrease.count += 1;

      // Calculate price for the increased item only
      const itemPrice = itemToIncrease.card.info.price / 100 || itemToIncrease.card.info.defaultPrice / 100;
      state.totalPrice += itemPrice;
      state.discountPrice = (state.totalPrice * 10) / 100;
      state.deliveryFees = (state.totalPrice * 5) / 100;
    }
  },

  // ... other reducers  

}
```